# Help on proof of convergent sequence without limit point

Tags: sequences-and-series

Please kindly help with this problem on converging sequence.

**Question** Determine whether the sequence $\bigl(\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n\bigr)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges and if it converges, guess its limits and prove your guess.

Now what I don't really understand is to proof the convergence of the sequence, because it has no limit point, so how do we prove it is convergent, and show me your guess.

Comment: What do you mean by "it has no limit point"? Are you referring to the undertext in $$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)\qquad?$$

Comment: See also [Evaluate the limit $\lim_{x\to \infty}( \sqrt{4x^2+x}-2x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1660120) and [How would you prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n)=\frac14$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/483481) Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csqrt%7B4n%5E2%2Bn%7D-2n%24&p=1).

Answer (score 2):

Your best option is to guess the limit. Note that\begin{align*}\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n&=\frac{\left(\sqrt{4n^2+n}-2n\right)\left(\sqrt{4n^2+n}+2n\right)}{\sqrt{4n^2+n}+2n}\\&=\frac n{\sqrt{4n^2+n}+2n}\\&=\frac1{\sqrt{4+\frac1n}+2}.\end{align*}I suppose that now it won't be difficult for you to guess the limit and to prove that your guess is right.

Comment: OK I think I understand now... But if I guess my limit to be $\frac{1}{4}$ , then can you show me how to proof my guess, I tried it using epsilon definition of convergency and I got stucked..

Comment: @AbubakarShafii $\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\frac1{\sqrt{4+\frac1n}+2}=\frac1{\lim_{n\in\mathbb N}\sqrt{4+\frac1n}+2}=\frac1{2+2}=\frac14$.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**
just use

$$\sqrt {A}-B=\frac {(\sqrt {A}-B)(\sqrt {A}+B)}{\sqrt {A}+B} $$
$$\frac {A-B^2}{\sqrt {A}+B} $$

and recompute le limit after a simplification.

Comment: OK I think I understand now... But if I guess my limit to be $\frac{1}{4}$, then can you show me how to proof my guess, I tried it using epsilon definition of convergency and I got stucked..